# Reactjs: render in dependence of render() function argument doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I use `React` and `Redux` and I want to avoid excessive `store` updating. My `input` component get its initial value from `store`, then it is changed by user, then it updates `store` when user press `submit button`. My thoughts are to run `render()` method  with `argument` and pass content to the component in dependence of `render() argument`. According to `console` output all go fine, but I see no anticipating changes in `DOM`!

Please help, I stuck.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class Clock extends Component {
  render(flag){
    let x = null;
    if( flag ){
      x = 5;
     console.log("Forced render, x = " + x);
   }else{
     x = 1;
     console.log("Render when mounts, x = " + x);
   }

    return (
     <div onClick = { this.handleClick.bind(this) } > { x } </div>
    )
  }

  handleClick(){
    console.log("Click!")
    this.render( true );
  }
}
```

Console output:

```
Clock.js:15 Render when mounts, x = 1
Clock.js:24 Click!
Clock.js:12 Forced render, x = 5
Clock.js:24 Click!
Clock.js:12 Forced render, x = 5
```

I want to see

```
<div> 5 </div>
```

but I get

```
<div> 1 </div>
```

No DOM changes.... (

Comment: I think `state` will fufill your need instead of doing this.

Comment: Is it a good practice in React-Redux to have both store and separated from the store state? And still interested why my code doesn't work, for scientific reasons :)

Comment: There is no need to have *everything* in the store - it could be argued that it's a good practice to keep everything you can in the local state instead of the global store.

Comment: Sagar and Sami - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use hadlClick to change the state. It will automatically re-render and then use the state to change the content.

```
export default class Clock extends Component {
  state = {
      flag: false
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState( prevState => ({flag: !prevState.flag }) );
  }

  render(){
    return (
     <div onClick = { this.handleClick } > { this.state ? 5 : 1;} </div>
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but I wondered how to do this without engaging state. I already have  props and click handler, the only thing I need - to re-render component. It seems strange for me why React doesn't act in this apparent way. Maybe my knowledge about React LifeCycle isn't full. By the way, in my code shouldComponentUpdate method doesn't fire before re-render. Ok, problem solved, thanks  a lot!